# why does the xpath that I write results in so many repeated result

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I am using scrapy shell.
Here is the html.
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjzLf.png)
***url:https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/***
What I wanted was the text in every span,but something disturbed me a lot.
First,I write this:

```
result = response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]')
result.xpath('//span[@class="text"]/text()')
```

than something strange came,here is the result from the shell

```
In [16]: result.xpath('//span[@class="text"]/text()')
Out[16]: 
[<Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The world as we have created it is a...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is our choices, Harry, that show ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“There are only two ways to live your...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The person, be it gentleman or lady,...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Imperfection is beauty, madness is g...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Try not to become a man of success. ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is better to be hated for what yo...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data="“I have not failed. I've just found 1...">,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A woman is like a tea bag; you never...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A day without sunshine is like, you ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The world as we have created it is a...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is our choices, Harry, that show ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“There are only two ways to live your...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The person, be it gentleman or lady,...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Imperfection is beauty, madness is g...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Try not to become a man of success. ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is better to be hated for what yo...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data="“I have not failed. I've just found 1...">,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A woman is like a tea bag; you never...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A day without sunshine is like, you ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The world as we have created it is a...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is our choices, Harry, that show ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“There are only two ways to live your...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The person, be it gentleman or lady,...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Imperfection is beauty, madness is g...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Try not to become a man of success. ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is better to be hated for what yo...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data="“I have not failed. I've just found 1...">,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A woman is like a tea bag; you never...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A day without sunshine is like, you ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The world as we have created it is a...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is our choices, Harry, that show ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“There are only two ways to live your...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The person, be it gentleman or lady,...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Imperfection is beauty, madness is g...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Try not to become a man of success. ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is better to be hated for what yo...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data="“I have not failed. I've just found 1...">,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A woman is like a tea bag; you never...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A day without sunshine is like, you ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The world as we have created it is a...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is our choices, Harry, that show ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“There are only two ways to live your...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The person, be it gentleman or lady,...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Imperfection is beauty, madness is g...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Try not to become a man of success. ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is better to be hated for what yo...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data="“I have not failed. I've just found 1...">,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A woman is like a tea bag; you never...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A day without sunshine is like, you ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The world as we have created it is a...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is our choices, Harry, that show ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“There are only two ways to live your...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The person, be it gentleman or lady,...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Imperfection is beauty, madness is g...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Try not to become a man of success. ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is better to be hated for what yo...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data="“I have not failed. I've just found 1...">,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A woman is like a tea bag; you never...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A day without sunshine is like, you ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The world as we have created it is a...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is our choices, Harry, that show ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“There are only two ways to live your...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The person, be it gentleman or lady,...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Imperfection is beauty, madness is g...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Try not to become a man of success. ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is better to be hated for what yo...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data="“I have not failed. I've just found 1...">,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A woman is like a tea bag; you never...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A day without sunshine is like, you ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The world as we have created it is a...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is our choices, Harry, that show ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“There are only two ways to live your...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The person, be it gentleman or lady,...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Imperfection is beauty, madness is g...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Try not to become a man of success. ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is better to be hated for what yo...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data="“I have not failed. I've just found 1...">,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A woman is like a tea bag; you never...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A day without sunshine is like, you ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The world as we have created it is a...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is our choices, Harry, that show ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“There are only two ways to live your...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The person, be it gentleman or lady,...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Imperfection is beauty, madness is g...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Try not to become a man of success. ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is better to be hated for what yo...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data="“I have not failed. I've just found 1...">,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A woman is like a tea bag; you never...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A day without sunshine is like, you ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The world as we have created it is a...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is our choices, Harry, that show ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“There are only two ways to live your...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“The person, be it gentleman or lady,...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Imperfection is beauty, madness is g...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“Try not to become a man of success. ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“It is better to be hated for what yo...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data="“I have not failed. I've just found 1...">,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A woman is like a tea bag; you never...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//span[@class="text"]/text()' data='“A day without sunshine is like, you ...'>]
```

It makes me doubtful about how xpath actually work.

I have tried css selector,it worked,but I just wondered why xpath would give me such a ridiculous result.Could you help me figure out this problem?Many thanks!It could help me know more about xpath.

Comment: please edit the question and post a [mcve]

Comment: I think you are looking at the text representation of a `Selector` object.  If my brief glance at the documentation is correct you need to call `.get()` or `getall()` to get values from the returned object. Something like `quotes = result.xpath('//span[@class="text"]/text()').getall()`

Comment: So  you don't know XPath but expect a certain result? And the one you get is not the expected? But which is the result you expected? And how about using minimal but complete samples included in the question to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Where did you look up the meaning of `//` in XPath, for instance, that you use it twice and expect a certain result but can't spell out which result you want or explain in plain English which elements or nodes you want to select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//span` selects all span elements in the document. If you only want those in the subtree of the context node, use `.//span`.